# How to select message list from MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Table in phpMyAdmin is:

[image: This is the table]

I want to select the username from **to** and **from** col in a single col and the result should be grouped by that single column. And my user id (**admin**) should not be included in the list.

Comment: Could you give some example like sample output if what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean "grouped by that single col"?  Some results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by using the UNION ALL operator of MySQL.

please find the query which may help you:

```
SELECT A.FROM AS 'USER' FROM TABLENAME AS A WHERE FROM <> 'admin'
UNION ALL
SELECT B.TO AS 'USER' FROM TABLENAME AS B WHERE FROM <> 'admin'
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This query might help you produce output according to your requirement...

```
select concat(to, from) as to_from from table_name 
where to <> 'admin' and from <> 'admin' group by to_from;
```

Answer (score 0):

use union and sub-query

```
select * from 
(select `to` as name from table_your
union
select `from` from table_your
) t where t.name!='admin'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9671f4/2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. I guess you want to **concatenate** two column, **group by** from and **admin** should  not be included in the column from(though you can remove both by using AND operator).

**from** and **to** are reserve word for MySql better avoid using in column name.

[image: Main table]

```
SELECT CONCAT(froms,tos) from admn WHERE froms <> 'admin' GROUP BY froms;
```

[image: After executing the query]